# A nonempty finite subset $U$ of $G$ is a subgroup if for all $x,y\in U$ also $xy$ is in $U$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

[image: Image_1]
This is from The Theory of Finite Groups, An Introduction by Kurzweil and  Stellmacher, New York, 2004.

I say this proof is extremely short.

How can you apply $\varphi$ to $1$?

$\varphi$ is defined over $U$ and then you need that $1$ belongs to $U$. But this is precisely what you want to proof.

A more detailed proof is this: let's define a function $\lambda: G\to G$, $g\lambda= gx$ where $x$ is a fixed element of $U$. $\lambda$ is a bijection. Let $\varphi=\lambda|U$. By hypothesis $\varphi$ is a function from $U$ to $U$. But $\lambda$ is injective so its restriction is injective too. So we have an injection from $U$ to $U$ and $U$ being finite therefor a bijection, that is $\varphi$ is bijective.

As $\varphi$ is surjective there exists $y\in U|y\varphi=x$. But $$1\lambda=x.\tag{1}$$
Now $y\varphi=y(\lambda|U)=y\lambda$ and $y\lambda=x$. But $\lambda$ is injection so $(1)$ gives $1=y\in U$.

In a similar way we can prove $x^{-1}\in U$. Wouldn't you say the proof in the book is far from being clear?

Comment: No, I think the proof in the book is quite lucid.

Comment: Could you explain why you think that?

Comment: The proof is entirely reasonable. They do **not** apply $\varphi$ to $1$ until after they've established that $1$ is in $U$; they establish that because the only element of $G$ that maps to $x$ is $1$, so $\varphi^{-1}(x)=1$. They do not "apply $\varphi$ to $1$" until after they've observed that $1\in U$. Your objection is unwarranted. Sure, you can add a bunch of justification for the argument that $1\in U$, which you do, but that isn't because the original proof is insufficient, or does something without warrant. It does not.

Comment: You say "the only element of G that maps to x is 1". What is the mapping here?

Comment: The mapping is $\varphi$, which is introduced in the first sentence of the proof: it is the map that sends an element $u$ to $ux$. What is the problem?

Comment: If the lurking objection is that $\varphi$ is only defined on $U$, then the answer is that $\varphi$ is known to be bijective on $U$, and so there is *something* mapping to $x$; that something has to be $1$, because $\varphi(u)=ux=x$ gives you $u=1$.

Comment: I understand. Thanks a lot Arturo.